# Slider is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a jQuery code that have all the pages code in one html file and I wanted to add a slider in the left side that will show the pages on. 
It works in the home page but it's not working for the other pages? Nevertheless the code is similar. I don't know what to change or add to make working for all of the pages.

My HTML header:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>WELCOME</title>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.sidr.dark.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        {$(".p1").hide()};
    $("#hide1").click(function(){
        $(".p1").hide();
    });
    $("#show1").click(function(){
        $(".p1").show();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        {$(".p2").hide()};
    $("#hide2").click(function(){
        $(".p2").hide();
    });
    $("#show2").click(function(){
        $(".p2").show();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        {$(".p3").hide()};
    $("#hide3").click(function(){
        $(".p3").hide();
    });
    $("#show3").click(function(){
        $(".p3").show();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#simple-menu1').sidr();
});
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#simple-menu2').sidr();
});
</script>



<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
```

And here is the home page slider (the one that works):

```
 <!-- Home Page --> 
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <div id="s-image"><a id="simple-menu1" href="#sidr"><img class="header-image" src="images/sort.png" alt="Sort By" heigh="35" width="35"></a> </div>
        <div id="sidr">
            <!-- Your content -->
            <ul class="center my-font">
                <li>
                    <a href="#page2" class="header-list">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#page3" class="header-list">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page4" class="header-list">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 class="my-font"> Welcome to the home page</h1> 
    </div>
```

Here is the code for the slider for the one of the pages (It didn't work):

```
  <!--  Page (2)  --> 
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div data-role="header">
        <div id="s-image"><a id="simple-menu1" href="#sidr"><img class="header-image" src="images/sort.png" alt="Sort By" heigh="35" width="35"></a> </div>
        <div id="sidr">
            <!-- Your content -->
            <ul class="center my-font">
                <li>
                    <a href="#page2" class="header-list">Page 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#" class="header-list">Page 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#page4" class="header-list">Page 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 class="my-font"> Welcome to the home page</h1> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What error do you have in console?

Comment: Are you sure you add your jQuery slider plugin  in another pages?

Comment: The error is that the slider is not working on the other pages. And what do you mean by adding the jQuery in another pages?

Comment: Try to open developer tools in browser and look in browser console on page where slider does not work's and post error in comment (if it will be). If you use sidr plugin you should include it on the page (in your head section I don't see sidr script)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to replace $ with jQuery . Or either you can check error on console .